# Xamarin Android component crash when Disposing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mono

We are using a 3rd party component called **Sharpnado.Forms.HorizontalListView**

Every time we want to dispose the object inside an Android Custom Renderer using:

```
Control.GetAdapter()?.Dispose();
```

The app crashes (see error stack bellow)

If we do not call Dispose we don't have the crash but we have potential memory leak.

Questions:

1 - Can we workaround this issue on our side or it depends only in the 3rd party component owner to fix it?

2 - Is there a different way to do this disposing?

Thanks

```
[MonoDroid] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[MonoDroid]   at Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms.Droid.Renderers.HorizontalList.AndroidHorizontalListViewRenderer+RecycleViewAdapter.get_ItemCount () [0x00000] in D:\Dev\Sharpnado\src\Xamarin-Forms-Practices\Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms\Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms.Droid\Renderers\HorizontalList\AndroidHorizontalListViewRenderer.RecycleViewAdapter.cs:93 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView+Adapter.n_GetItemCount (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <7cd821e41c6245e986359cd08947256b>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.88(intptr,intptr)
...
[AppCenterCrashes] Unhandled Exception from source=AndroidEnvironment
[AppCenterCrashes] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms.Droid.Renderers.HorizontalList.AndroidHorizontalListViewRenderer+RecycleViewAdapter.get_ItemCount () [0x00000] in D:\Dev\Sharpnado\src\Xamarin-Forms-Practices\Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms\Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms.Droid\Renderers\HorizontalList\AndroidHorizontalListViewRenderer.RecycleViewAdapter.cs:93 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView+Adapter.n_GetItemCount (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <7cd821e41c6245e986359cd08947256b>:0 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.88(intptr,intptr)
...
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes[0x7096654600] -> System.Core[0x70966d7c00]: 20
...
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_byte_array'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_byte_array'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_byte_array'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_set_byte_array_region'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_set_byte_array_region'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_set_byte_array_region'.
[zygote64] Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk:classes2.dex
[zygote64] Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk:classes2.dex
[zygote64] JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_throw'.
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the latest version? I believe a fix for this was pushed last week.

Comment: Yeah I updated to 0.9.11 but the issue remains

Comment: The adapter that you are trying to dispose is your custom one?

Comment: it the custom RecycleViewAdapter within the 3rd party component